# wxpython: Transparent panel in wxpython

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

It is possible to make the whole frame transparent using `SetTransparent(val)` in wxpython. But can I make a single panel in it to be transparent?

I tried using `panelobj.SetTransparent(val)` but that didnt work.

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title,size=(250, 250))

        topPanel = wx.Panel(self)

        panel1 = wx.Panel(topPanel, -1)
        panel1.SetTransparent(100)
        panel2 = wx.Panel(topPanel, -1)
        panel2.SetBackgroundColour('gray')

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(panel1,1,flag = wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL)
        sizer.Add(panel2,1,flag = wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL)

        topPanel.SetSizer(sizer)



class MyApp(wx.App):
     def OnInit(self):
         frame = MyFrame(None, -1, 'frame')
         frame.Show(True)
         return True

app = MyApp(0)
app.MainLoop()
```

supposing I want to set transparency for panel1.

Comment: What does [`panel1.CanSetTransparent()`](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Window-class.html#CanSetTransparent) return?

Comment: And what platform are you on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's platform-specific which windows can and can't be made transparent.

The [`CanSetTransparent`](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Window-class.html#CanSetTransparent) method allows you to check whether a window's transparency can be toggled at runtime. If it returns false, `SetTransparent` will (usually) do nothing, and you shouldn't call it.

Off the top of my head (but don't quote me on this—it must be documented somewhere, but I can't find it…):

- Mac OS X with Cocoa build: anything can be transparent.
- Mac OS X with Carbon build (which nobody uses anymore): only top-level windows can be transparent.
- Windows: only top-level windows can be transparent.
- X11 with compositor: anything can be transparent.
- X11 without compositor: nothing can be transparent.
- Wayland (which is still experimental): anything can be transparent.

However, Windows is a special case. While you can't toggle a sub-window's transparency, or set it to a percentage, you *can* make it fully transparent at creation time, as shown in [ρss's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29942182/908494).

So, if that's what you're looking for, and you want to do it as portably as possible, you'll want something like this:

```
style = wx.TRANSPARENT_WINDOW if sys.platform.lower() == 'win32' else 0
panel1 = wx.Panel(topPanel, -1, style=style)
if panel1.CanSetTransparent:
    panel1.SetTransparent(100)
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes it is possible. You can use [style=wx.TRANSPARENT_WINDOW](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Window-class.html)

**Sample code**: I made the `panel1` transparent and gave green color to `topPanel`. Thats why you see green color on top of `panel2` because the `panel1` is transparent.

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title,size=(250, 250))
        topPanel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        topPanel.SetBackgroundColour('green')
        panel1 = wx.Panel(topPanel, -1, style=wx.TRANSPARENT_WINDOW)
        #panel1.SetTransparent(100)
        panel2 = wx.Panel(topPanel, -1)
        panel2.SetBackgroundColour('gray')

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(panel1,1,flag = wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL)
        sizer.Add(panel2,1,flag = wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL)

        topPanel.SetSizer(sizer)



class MyApp(wx.App):
     def OnInit(self):
         frame = MyFrame(None, -1, 'frame')
         frame.Show(True)
         return True

app = MyApp(0)
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I believe `wx` leaves it platform-specific which kinds of windows can be made transparent at runtime, which can only be made transparent at construction time, and which can't be made transparent at all. Even top-level `Frame`s aren't guaranteed to handle transparency (e.g., on X11 systems without a compositor, they can't be). That's what the `CanSetTransparent` function is for. So, the fact that this works on your computer doesn't mean it will work on his.

Comment: On the other hand, if this _doesn't_ work on his computer, I think that means nothing will work (well, short of digging down to the actual native window handles and calling native functions via `ctypes` or a wrapper, which I doubt he wants to do…), so I'm not sure what better answer anyone could write.

Comment: Yes @abarnert you are right and I am left. :P My answer will work on Windows OS only. As the link I provided in my answer clearly states that.