# wxPython Frame Background transparent

Tags: python, wxpython, frame, transparent

Another question to wxpython.

I have a Frame with (at the moment) 3 Panels. All of them contain *.png pictures with transparent parts.
But behind these transparent parts there is the grey from the Frame background.
What I want is just a transparent background, that I can see for example my Desktop or whatever is behind the programm in that moment.

All I found was `SetTransparent(0)` but this made the full programm transparent and the other thing was to change the shape, but that dosen't made anything, except change width/heigth, if the shape has not the same properties.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29941789/wxpython-transparent-panel-in-wxpython

Comment: Wrong answer, your link is about a Panel, not the Frame!

Comment: Paraphrasing, "I have 3 `panels`, each contains a picture".

Comment: Yeah, and the Panels are transparent. It's just in the next sentence...
What I want is what the title says: A transparent **Frame** background